# accessing the next field of a list Node gives a NullPointerException. Why?

Tags: java, list

I defined a nested Node class inside a class named 'Structure', and

```
class HNode<T extends ArrayList> {
private T _datum;
private HNode<T> _prev;
private HNode<T> _next;

public HNode(T datum, HNode<T> prev, HNode<T> next) {
    _datum = datum;
    _prev = prev;
    _next = next;
}

public HNode<T> getNext() {
    return _next;
}
```

and I designated _datum, _prev, and _next fields manually when I created this Node class.

```
_r0 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(3), _r0, _r1);
_r1 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(4), _r0, _r2);
_r2 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(5), _r1, _pos3);
_pos3 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(6), _r2, _pos4);
_pos4 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(7), _pos3, _pos5);
```

(this is a part of the initialization. _al is a ArrayList of ArrayList, for which I used to call Collections.shuffle(_al) method.)

When I tested getNext() method with a JUnit Test(@Test)

```
public void getNextTest() {
    Structure st = new Structure();
    HNode<ArrayList<String>> six = st.getSix(); 
    six.getNext().add("KKK");
    String actual = st.getSeven().getDatum().get(0); 
    String expected = "KKK";
    assertTrue(" ", actual == expected);
}
```

getSix() returns _pos3, and getSeven() returns _pos4(next to _pos3) (temporary methods).
Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: try to log the sizes of your lists. your lists may not be instantiated correctly at some point.

Comment: Can you please post the entire error message and point out the offending statement?

Comment: I ran JUnit Test and it just says 'java.lang.NullPointerException at xx.Tests.getNextTest(Test.java:17)' where line 17 is six.getNext().add("KKK");

Comment: that means your `getNext()` is returning null. could you show how `Structure` was constructed?

Comment: In `assertTrue` are you sure that you want to compare object references and not the strings themselves? I mean shouldn't it be `actual.equals(expected)`?

Comment: @Oneb - or, possibly, `six` itself is `NULL`. In either case (as you suggested) OP should look at his `Structure` class and its default constructor first.

Comment: @PM77-1, +1 that could also be the case. :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here it is going wrong :

```
_pos4 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(7), _pos3, _pos5);
```

you have assigned **_pos5** as next element, but I think you have never initialized it. So this value is null by default. Now if you try to access any method on a null reference you will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: I initialized it after I initialized _pos4. It's  _pos5 = new HNode<ArrayList<String>>(_al.get(8), _pos4, _pos6);
Do you mean it's a problem because I am using _pos5 as argument before I initialize it?

Comment: Maybe you're right... I tested getPrev method and it worked fine... Thank you.. Then what can I do now? Define a setter method for the next field?

Comment: Make sure you initialize all the fields. Yes you have to initialize it before you pass it to _pos4 constructor. This is because eventually you are passing a null value to _pos constructor and then initializing it, but value passed to constructor still remains null and causes problem.

Comment: what you might want to do is instantiate things before you use them as so they will not refer to NULL. @user25409

Comment: @user25409 - Even before that in the very first statement you're defining `_r0` using `_r1` which is seemingly initialized in the next statement.